# Ubuntu Center closes after opening it!

Tags: software-center

this is my third day as an Ubuntu User and it's great!

The only problem I had is that today I noticed that the Ubuntu Download Center doesnt work anymore.

I searched on the Internet and there are few answers all based on code typing but unfortunately I dont know any of that stuff.

Can someone help me please!
Thanks!

Comment: There are older and more stable (reliable) tools with a graphical user interface, that can do the same thing. *Synaptic* is such a tool. It takes a little longer to learn, but it works very well and is worth the effort to learn how to use it. The following command line will install it, `sudo apt install synaptic`

Comment: It would help us if you opened a terminal, ran `software-center`, copy-pasted the output, and posted it here